# (OS X) Pure Data sort of freezes when selecting an aggregate device in the audio settings

Tags: macos, audio, puredata

OS X has this great functionality called "aggregate devices." It allows you to merge multiple sound cards into one virtual device. I want to use this functionality to send different sounds to different outputs, via Pure Data.

I actually did manage to get my aggregate device to work with Pure Data, last Thursday. Now, for some reason, it won't let me. In the Audio Settings of Pure Data, if I select my aggregate device, the settings window closes and it's impossible to open it again or open any patch. Even quitting the application doesn't work, I have to kill it by force.

I've already spent a big part of the night on this, so... if by any chance someone has even the beginning of an idea...
Thanks!

Comment: I think this question would be a better match for some PD users group. I see nothing generic to OSX audio in your question. There can be too many particular reasons why this may or may not work (aggregating possible custom interface protocols for third party audio cards, and matching them with PD low-level OSX audio, just to mention one). Last but not least, SO is about programming,  it would be a safer bet to report this problem to the PD developers.

Comment: Yes I guess it could be closed as "not a real question." Actually the reason was a weird problem of the USB hub that wasn't powerful enough to power the two USB soundcards. I just swapped the Arduino cable and one of the two soundcards, and it worked…